# if cursor inside div then display block jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

**Here is a jsfiddle of the problem:**
http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/

I want it so when you hover over anywhere in the footer the toggledown will become active and will remain active until you move the mouse from the footer.

Comment: Can you be more specific? E.g. what kind of "toggle animation" are you talking about?

Comment: Sounds like you have more jQuery--can you post the code that affects the footer as well?

Comment: slidetoggle ......... updated my post

Comment: I'm a bit confused, what needs to be `display: block;`? You need to check for that before doing anything or you need to set it to that? And what does the click do? What is the animation? Is it causing a different element to be mvoed under your mouse and the original one to be moved out?

Comment: added my footer toggle code....

Comment: wow, it's becoming longer and longer. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Comment: yes here is the problem: http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/   (sorry)

Comment: @Chris: can you help i added a jsfiddle..

Comment: The main problem does indeed seem to be that as you animate things your mouse is moved off of the hover and so it triggers the leaving hover thing to hide everything... I would suggest that before you ask for any more help though you trim all the extraneous javascript out of that fiddle. Large amounts of it are irrelevant to the problem and I am personally finding it hard to find the relevant bits among the rest. When asking a question its always best to have the minimal working example to work from. And sometimes in creating such a thing you solve your own problem too. :)

Comment: trimmed: http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is the following line:

```
    jQuery('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: jQuery("#footer_copy_right").offset().top
    }, 'slow');
```

This causes the whole page to move adn thus the item you were hovering over is no longer being hovered over so it triggers your event again and hides your text. When I was testing this was causing the hover content to move back under my mouse and thus trigger again...

I would personally not use hover in this situation and let the user click to expand and then click again to collapse.

If you want to keep using the hover option then you need to decide what the event to trigger the collapse should be. Clearly the current choice (mouse no longer over the arrow) is insufficient.

Often what I will do is attach the hover to a block containing the visible triggering block as well as the contents that are going to be displayed. This way your content won't collapse until you have moved off the newly displayed content.

http://jsfiddle.net/AjHwM/ is an example of such a thing.

Comment: perfect... i agree the click option is much better!

Answer (score 1):

Even if I'm not sure what your actual goal is, maybe the `document.elementFromPoint()` method is what helps you out here.

It is invoked like

```
if( document.elementFromPoint( event.pageX, event.pageY ) === $('#footer')[0] ) { }
```

That code, within your `hover` aka `mouseenter` / `mouseleave` handlers, would compare the node which lays under the current absolute mouse cursor X/Y positions against the `#footer` node.

Ref.: [MDN doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/document.elementFromPoint), [W3C doc](http://dev.w3.org/csswg/cssom-view/#dom-document-elementfrompoint)

Comment: here is a jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/MEJgb/, some good info you have provided, up vote from me.

Comment: well, ever event handler function gets passed in the *event object*. you can just access it within your `hover` handler, by passing in *event* into your `function( event ) { }`. The `[0]` behind the jQuery contructor makes sure we're addressing the underlaying DOM node, not the jQuery object, since `.elementFromPoint` will also return a DOM node.